# Is it better to use inline style or Material's Box component to handle spacing?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a uniform spacing for my elements, so instead of using margin, I came across using `<Box\>`.

Any one have any insight on what is more efficient to use?

```
<div style={{ padding: "0px 16px" }}>
  {children}
</div>
```

VS

```
<div>
  <Box sx={{ mt: InputFieldVerticalSpacing }} />
  {children}
</div>
```

Comment: It's up to you how you want to design and implement your project, though `Box` is meant to be used as a wrapper, it's not really meant as a spacer component. At this point, using `padding` is totally fine.

Comment: To ensure a uniform spacing across your app, the [material ui theming API](https://mui.com/customization/theming/) is probably your best bet.